# Example of a ring of finite global dimension with flat qu0tient

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra, algebras, global-dimension

I've been thinking about this for quite a while but I cannot seem to find an example of

---

If $k$ is a commutative ring of finite global dimension and I'm looking for a strictly not-commutative $k$-algebra $A$, which is $k$-flat and there is an ideal $I$ in $A$ such that $A/I$ is a regular commutative ring which is $k$-flat also....

**Edit:**  and I is generated by an element which is not a unit not a zero divisor and it commutes with all the elements of A...

(the flatness condition seems to really restrict my possibilities....)

Comment: Can't you just take $A$ to be the algebra of upper triangular $2\times 2$ matrices over $k$, and $I$ the ideal consisting of matrices whose first column is zero? Then $A$ is not only $k$-flat, but free, and $A/I\cong k$.

Comment: I doubt this is possible with the flatness condition...  I'll have to check the details later...

Comment: "regular commutative" means "commutative"? Or you are asking for a particular version of "regular"? And your edit precludes Artinian rings from consideration... maybe that's what was interfering?

Comment: it means commutative and regular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let k be a field, let A be the enveloping algebra of the three-dimensional Heisenberg Lie algebra g, and let I be the ideal of A generated by any nonzero element of the center of g.

This satisfies all your conditions.

Comment: Jeremy's example in the comment above is not generated by a central element. This is a natural way to fix that.

Comment: Thanks Mariano I've been thinking about that one for a very long while.